# AS3 - Auto refreshing display after updating array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, refresh

So, basically I'm reinventing the wheel by trying to make a sort of spreadsheet in flash for tracking member growth in a game.  In this one section I'm adding member names to an array and then placing the names into dynamically created tiles with text fields attached to display the name.

I have a save button which saves the array, and if I save, close, and reopen, then I can see the members I have added.  However, I would like it to refresh the stage as soon as the array is changed to reflect the changes made (update the spreadsheet).  I will also be adding and removing other tiles dynamically, but I can extrapolate the solution to this problem to all of those later.

Here's the code I have to add members and create the display:

```
public var mainArray:Array = new Array;
public var i1:Number = 0;
public var memberBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
public var MAX_ROWS = 0;
public var MAX_COLS = 0;

public function Tracker() {
    MAX_COLS = mainArray.length - 1;
    addBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addFun); //atchaed to button on stage
    public function addFun($e:MouseEvent):void{
        mainArray[i1] = [];
        mainArray[i1][0] = addNameTxt.text //attached to textfield on stage
        i1++;
        loadMembers();

    public function loadMembers():void{

        var multiDimensionalArray:Array = new Array();


        //initalize the arrays
        for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
        {
            var boolArray:Array = new Array();

            for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++){
                boolArray.push(false);
            }

            multiDimensionalArray.push(boolArray);
        }

        //now we can set the values of the array as usual
        for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++){

                multiDimensionalArray.push(1); ;
            }
        }
        //create a column of tiles based on mainArray length with a textfield attached to each
        buildLevel(multiDimensionalArray);

    }

        public function buildLevel(s:Array){
            var txtArray:Array = new Array();
            memberBox.name = "tileHolder";
            for(var i=0; i  < MAX_ROWS + 1; i++){
                for(var o=0; o < MAX_COLS + 1; o++){
                    var currentTile:MemberBox = new MemberBox();
                    currentTile.x = i*150;
                    currentTile.y = o*25;
                    currentTile.name = "b"+o;
                    memberBox.addChild(currentTile);
                    //currentTile.gotoAndStop(int(s[o][i]));
                    var memberTxt:TextField=new TextField(); 
                    currentTile.addChild(memberTxt);
                    memberTxt.width = 150;
                    memberTxt.height = 25;
                    txtArray[o] = memberTxt;
                    txtArray[o].text = mainArray[o][0];

                    }

                }

                memberBox.x = 60;
                memberBox.y = 170;
                addChild(memberBox);

            }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to attach event listeners to the Array, however, Arrays don't fire events.

**Solution #1: Managed Updates**

Rather than allowing any piece of code to modify your array directly, write a function that handles updating your array.  This way, you can know when to update the display at the same time.

```
public var mainArray:Array = new Array;
public var i1:Number = 0;
public var memberBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
public var MAX_ROWS = 0;
public var MAX_COLS = 0;

public function Tracker() {
    MAX_COLS = mainArray.length - 1;
    addBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addFun); //attached to button on stage

    public function addFun(e:MouseEvent):void {
        mainArray[i1] = [];
        mainArray[i1][0] = addNameTxt.text //attached to textfield on stage
        i1++;
        loadMembers();
    }

    public function loadMembers():void {
        var multiDimensionalArray:Array = new Array();

        //initalize the arrays
        for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) {
            var boolArray:Array = new Array();

            for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++) {
                boolArray.push(false);
            }

            multiDimensionalArray.push(boolArray);
        }

        //now we can set the values of the array as usual
        for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++) {
                multiDimensionalArray.push(1); ;
            }
        }
        //create a column of tiles based on mainArray length with a textfield attached to each
        buildLevel(multiDimensionalArray);

    }

    public function buildLevel(s:Array) {
        var txtArray:Array = new Array();
        memberBox.name = "tileHolder";
        for (var i:int = 0; i < MAX_ROWS + 1; i++) {
            for(var o=0; o < MAX_COLS + 1; o++) {
                var currentTile:MemberBox = new MemberBox();
                currentTile.name = i + "_" + o;
                currentTile.x = i*150;
                currentTile.y = o*25;
                memberBox.addChild(currentTile);
                //currentTile.gotoAndStop(int(s[o][i]));
                var memberTxt:TextField=new TextField(); 
                currentTile.addChild(memberTxt);
                memberTxt.width = 150;
                memberTxt.height = 25;
                txtArray[o] = memberTxt;
                txtArray[o].text = mainArray[o][0];
            }
        }

        memberBox.x = 60;
        memberBox.y = 170;
        addChild(memberBox);
    }

    public function modifyArray(row:int, col:int, value:*):void {
        // Update our array.
        mainArray[row][col] = value;

        // Update our tile.
        var tile:MemberBox = memberBox.getChildByName(row + "_" + col);
        tile.getChildAt(0).text = value;
    }
}
```

When you actually modified your array, you'd do that with your function, rather than a direct `mainArray[o][i]` approach.

```
// Instead of this
mainArray[o][i] = "foo";

// You'd do this
modifyArray(o, i, "foo");
```

***Update:*** I'm not sure how better to explain this, so I've posted working example that you can view.  It contains the class, and the document code, the fla, and the swf with working updates to the spreadsheet.  Let me know if that resolves the issue: [SpreadSheet Test @ Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2xkbn22etlozdo/AABjnqS-m2zZaBobbwyiLwhRa?dl=0)

**Solution #2: Poll for Changes**

Hold two versions of your array in memory.  The first is the one you're actively editing, the second is an untouched duplicate to compare against the first.  Every so often (once per second?) you iterate over the entire dataset and look for differences.  When one is found, update the duplicate array and the displayed spreadsheet.

Here's an example of how you'd do that:

```
import flash.utils.*;

var last:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();
this.addEventListener("enterFrame", checkData);

var foo:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
var fooBackup:Array = [];

function update():void {
    var txt:TextField;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        // If we don't have a representation of this index, create one.
        if (!this.getChildByName("tile"+i)) {
            txt = new TextField();
            txt.name = "tile" + i;
            txt.text = foo[i];
            this[txt.name] = txt;
            addChild(txt);
            txt.y = i * 20;
        }

        // Update the data if inconsistent.
        txt = this.getChildByName("tile"+i) as TextField;
        if (fooBackup.hasOwnProperty(i) == false || foo[i] != fooBackup[i]) {
            fooBackup[i] = foo[i]
            txt.text = foo[i];
            trace("Index " + i + " changed.  Updated backup, and display.");
        }
    }
}

function checkData(e:Event):void {
    var now:Number = flash.utils.getTimer();

    // If the last time we checked is greater than a second, run the check again.
    if (now - last > 1000) {
        // Update last checked index;
        last += 1000;

        // For the sake of argument, let's randomly change an index to a random value.
        foo[random(0, foo.length-1)] = random(-1000, 1000);
        update();
    }
}

 function random(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number {
    /* Returns a random number between the low and high values given. */
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}
```

**Solution #3: Roll your own Array**

As outlined by Adobe's [Extending the Array class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8d829-7fde.html), you can subclass Arrays and from there add your own event dispatches when you add/remove entries.  This is the more adventurous solution, and (in my humble opinion) the best as it maintains code consistency, while giving broad and efficient powers.

Comment: multiDimensionalArray is just a temp array used to store the tiles and then return them.  mainArray holds the actual data I am working with.  That being said...I don't really understand your answer to be honest...  Could you put the example in context of the rest of the code?

Comment: Thank you for the expanded answer.  However, nowhere in your example code is modifyArray actually called.  I'm struggling to see how this fits in...

Comment: I'm assuming you're modifying your array outside of the `Tracker` class.  If so, you'd call the `modifyArray` method from the same place.

Comment: Thank you again for your help!  I'm trying method 2 but keep getting the error `#1006: getChildByName is not a function.`  --- Method 1 makes sense, but it does the reverse of what I need.  mainArray[o][i] is the "foo".  I need `text = mainArray[o][0];`

Comment: `getChildByName` can only be called from classes that extend `DisplayObjectContainer` (such as a MovieClip or Sprite).  If you run the above code from document code (MainTimeline), it will work fine, or make sure that the class you're placing the code extends Sprite or MovieClip.  See http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/children/display_api.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain solution #1 better, so I've added an example project you can view.  The link is in the answer above.